# Run commands in container after deploy with Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

**Scenario:**
Elastic Beanstalk Environment with Multi Docker platform.
NGinx container and PHP7.1 Container
PHP/Symfony application

**Problem:**
I need to run Doctrine cli command after deploy to update database. I figured out how to do this dynamically but not **automatically** with following code.

```
docker exec $(docker ps | grep php-fpm | awk '{print $1}') php ./bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

I deploy with CodePipeline/CodeBuild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your Dockerfile

```
CMD ["/start.sh"]
```

In your start.sh file

```
#!/bin/sh
set -xe

php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```